# Pass NSManagedObject from one view controller to another

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, nsmanagedobject

I'm developing a table view based app using CoreData with Swift. I'm trying to pas an NSManagedObject from one view controller to another. Below is my code and error that I get.

In `ViewController1.swift` I have the following code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if segue.identifier == "Edit" {
        var selectedItem: NSManagedObject = myData[self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow().row] as NSManagedObject
        let vc2: ViewController2 = segue.destinationViewController as ViewController2

        vc2.item = selectedItem

    }
}
```

In `ViewController2.swift`:

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    @NSManaged var item : NSManagedObject

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    // Other default func
}
```

Error when I segue to `ViewController2`:

```
[_TtC6myData18ViewController2 setItem:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x111530000
```

Comment: Try deleting the @NSManaged, it's my understanding that's only supposed to be used in NSManagedObject subclasses, not view controllers.

Comment: @rdelmar when I do that it says that class ViewController2 has no initializer

Comment: var item : NSManagedObject! or var item : NSManagedObject? I'm not sure which you should use.

Comment: That removes the error but then says that cannot assign to item in vc2 @rdelmar

Comment: Does it work if you put it in an init method without the ! or ?, init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        var item : NSManagedObject
    }

Comment: @rdelmar super init isn't called before returning from initializer. Thats the error I get when I add the init method in: class ViewController2: UIViewController { here }

Comment: @rdelmar this worked actually var item : NSManagedObject! I made a mistake by changing var to let for some reason. You can answer the question properly so I can mar it as a right answer. Thanks for your help bro :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The @NSManaged qualifier is only supposed to be used for properties in an NSManagedObject subclass, so it shouldn't be used in your situation. This should work,

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    var item : NSManagedObject! 

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    // Other default func
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a breakpoint on exceptions so that you can see what the actual error/message in the `NSException` is. You will also be able to see where it is thrown.

Comment: I did that and I got [_TtC6myData18ViewController2 setItem:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x111530000 Any idea what this means bro?